# 'JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h' file not found after update/installing new pode

Tags: cocoapods, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I installed all the new Firebase Pods ('Firebase/Storage', 
pod 'Firebase/Database' etc..) with terminal , but when I am trying to run my project I get the error.
 [image: error in my bridge header]

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix the issue by removing the '~> 7.2.0’ in my Podfile at the

```
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController’, '~> 7.2.0’ line
```

maybe it will help somebody

https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1586

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this is due to the Cocoapod links not being correct. I often find this with projects and a seemingly random file is not found.

Steps I would recommend:

1. Delete your .xcworkspace file
2. Delete the Podfile.lock and Pods folder
3. Close Xcode
4. Call pod update to update your pod links
5. Open using the .xcworkspace file
6. Clean project

Another useful thing to note is that often Cocoapods does not work well with Dropbox. This is due to the information cached being stored in the direct folder space. If this issue is occurring with projects then it is worth zipping the file and completing the above steps in a non Dropbox file.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I just forced Xcode to build, pressing `cmd b`. It solved.